# why jquery on() not work on image load event

Tags: jquery

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $('<img class="halfsize" src="imgs/logo.png?' + Math.random() + '" alt="" />').appendTo('header');
});
$('img').on('load', function (evt) {
    console.log(this, evt);
});
```

This code work fine when page first load. But, when click img, new append to header's img not trigger the load event, why? Click event is work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some browsers (IE in particular), you MUST attach the onload handler BEFORE you assign the `.src` attribute.  That's because some browsers will load an image immediately when you assign the `.src` attribute if the image is in the image cache.  Thus, if you attach the `load` handler afterwards, the event will already have occurred and you may miss the event entirely.

The `load` event does not propagate so you cannot use delegated event handling for it.

In your case, I would suggest this code for safe, proper behavior in all browsers that attaches the load handler first:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $('<img class="halfsize" alt="" />')
        .on('load', function (evt) {
            console.log(this, evt);
         })
        .attr("src", "imgs/logo.png?" + Math.random())
        .appendTo('header');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `click` works because you use the delegated form of `.on()`.

You should do the same with the image..

```
$('header').on('load','img', function( evt ){
    console.log(this, evt);
} );
```

---

**Update** Seems that image load events do not bubble up the DOM (*so you cannot handle them through delegated event handlers*)..

So you will have to manually add your handler to the dynamically added images..

```
function loadHandler(evt){
    console.log(this, evt);
}
$('body').on('click', 'img',function(){ 
    $('<img/>', {
        'class':'halfsize',
        load: loadHandler,
        alt:'',
        src: 'imgs/logo.png?'+ Math.random()
    }).appendTo('header'); 
});

$('img').on('load', loadHandler);
```

Comment: Yes, according to documentation of "on" function ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ ), "load", "scroll" and "error" events do not bubble and, therefore, could not be delegated.

Comment: Your second version will not work reliably in some versions of IE because you MUST assign the `onload` handler BEFORE the `.src` value is set or you may miss the `onload` event entirely.

Comment: Your code doesn't for sure assign the `src` after `load`.  When jQuery iterates over the properties of the object you pass to apply them to the object, it just uses the `for prop in obj` construct which does not guarantee any order of the properties.

Comment: If you change img src instead of appendTo header,  seems to cause many calls to the event exponentially. Each click increases the number of calls the event "load"